# convert jQuery array to php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my jQuery Array:

```
var IDs=[];
    $("#tags").find('.suggested-tag').each(function(){IDs.push(this.id);});
```

and I want convert this array in `php` array what should I?

Comment: could you please post an example of your js array

Comment: Convert your array to JSON string (`JSON.stringify`), send it with AJAX to your PHP script and then `json_decode`.

Answer (score 3):

If your array is in JSON format, you could write its contents within a hidden form field.

Then, when the form is submitted, you are able to read the field contents (still in JSON format) and convert it to php array through:

```
$some_array = json_decode($var_containing_json_text);
```

You can read more about `json_decode()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly.PHP works server-side and JQuery works client-side So You can't use Js varaibles in PHP
But there is a trick that you can use Ajax to send Js variables to PHP. This is the only way.